# Is there a common way of concatenating strings across different SQL database providers i.e. Oracle, Postgresql, SQL Server and DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, oracle, postgresql

We have an application that provides support for 4 different SQL databases: Oracle, SQL server, Postgresql, and DB2.

I want to write a common java code for all of them to create a DDL which will concatenate several strings.
As there are different operators used across the above-mentioned database providers, I want to know is there a common way that can bridge this gap?

Comment: No. No database product follows the SQL standard beyond a basic compliance level. Which is quite understandable, since the ANSI SQL process is *slooow*. All database vendors add custom functionality and *then* try to get their version standardized.

Comment: ANSI SQL feature E021-07, "Character concatenation" compliance for some products can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance.

Comment: see my answer below. In fact, I have developed sql generating system that can generate sql for any db language. It is very useful for times when you get users drug and click  interfaces to design data queries. Their actions result in collection of object that later can be used by a processor to generate language-specific syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The standard string concatenation operator is `||`. It is supported in Oracle, Postgres and DB2, but alas not in SQL Server (it uses `+` instead).

`concat()` should be a viable alternative, that works across all 4 databases.

While this may solve your immediate question, that relates to string concatenation, there are *many* other features that do vary across databases. Writing portable queries is not something that can easily be done, left apart a limited set of very simple cases.

Comment: Note that `concat()` in Oracle only accepts two parameters, while the other DBMS support multiple parameters

Comment: You will also have the deal the how Oracle and Postgres handle nulls.  For example the expression " 'A' || null" produces 'A' in Oracle and 'null' in Postgres. The CONCAT function would produce 'A' for each, heed the above note.  And that just the beginning of issues. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create abstracting method

Pseudo code

```
class SqlConcat
{
    private List<string> _parts;

    void AddLiteral(string part)
    {
         _parts.Add("'" + part + "'");
    }

    void Add(string part)
    {
         _parts.Add(part);
    }

    string Generate(dbEngine db, string alias)
    {
       if (db == sqlserver)
           return string.Join(" + ", _parts) + " AS " + alias;
       else if (db == oracle | db == postgres | db == db2)
           return string.Join(" || ", _parts) + " AS " + alias;
       else if (db == mysql)
           return "Concat(" + string.Join(", ", _parts) + ") as " + alias;
       else
           ....
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if `part` contains a `'`?

Comment: @muistooshort This is a pseudo-code and shown as concept-only. Any details are irrelevant. The language itself is undefined. The OP will have to translate this into JAVA and take care of the all relevant details.